# Excel chart to show timeline of case load

Tags: excel, graph

I've finished entering a chunk of data and would really appreciate some help with the visualization.

I have columns for the Case ID, Agent name, Start time, and Stop time. I would really like to have a chart with a timeline on the x axis, count on the y axis, and a line/bar for each agent showing how many cases they had at a time at any given time going across the timeline.

I hope this makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Showing the work you've already done and any errors you encountered along the way is much more likely to elicit answers, vs. asking others to produce the result you'd like.  See here for this site's guidelines on asking questions- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RichieThomas I apologize, I've tried using a few different chart options and a pivot table, but I'm not having any luck figuring out how to account for the duration of time between the start time and end time, and the count of cases being worked at that time.